# How to manipulate accented files on Unix?

Tags: bash, unix

On our CMS that went through many versions and hosting platforms, we just came across an accented image file that would not work from it's url. So I ssh'd onto the box and tried to rename it.

However, I could not figure out how to type in it's name correctly. For instance, I know that if a file is called `my file.txt` you would do something like `mv my\ file.txt my_new_file.txt` but how do you move a file called `café.txt`?

In the end, I used a wildcard and did `mv caf*.txt cafe.txt` but I'm still wondering why this accented image would not work in the first place, and what would have been the proper way to handle it on unix.

Comment: What terminal were you using ? The terminal is responsible for handling the encoding, the issue might stem from the terminal temporarily falling back to a different encoding, hiding the true nature of the error to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using bash:

Just to see my files:

```
$ ls
café.txt
```

Check the hex bytes of the file name (note: mine may be different... mine are probably UTF-8 encoded):

```
$ echo * | hexdump -C
00000000  63 61 66 c3 a9 2e 74 78  74 0a                    |caf...txt.|
0000000a
```

Then craft a file name using the hex codes for the parts that aren't found on your keyboard:

```
$ ls $'caf\xc3\xa9.txt'
café.txt
```

In bash, $' ... ' will expand escapes (much like "echo -e" does). And \x followed by a 2 digit hex code will replace it with that character.

And I don't see anything wrong with an:

```
ls caf*.txt
```

followed by a

```
mv caf*.txt cafe.txt
```

But if for some reason that would match multiple files, you can use the hex stuff:

```
ls $'caf\xc3\xa9.txt'
mv $'caf\xc3\xa9.txt' café.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix filesystems store filenames as raw sequence of bytes. The kernel doesn't know or cares about what the names really are.

It is up to the applications accessing them to use the proper encoding to display non ASCII characters properly. The usual way is through the LC_ALL/LC_* or LANG environment variables. I would recommend to use an UTF-8 locale on all applications accessing the file system to avoid incompatibilities/inconsistencies.